# auto repeat the up/down arrow key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

in firefox when im inside a input textbox and press down the up/down arrow key it doesn't autorepeat. how can i make that happen and control how many keypress it will fire up per sec?

UPDATE: i use:

```
$('#search_view #search').live('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 40) {
       // code
    }
});
```

but it just execute the code one time..i would like it to repeat when holding down the down-arrow.

Comment: In what context? Works fine for me when scrolling a document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.keydown()`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) instead ..

quote from jQuery [.keypress()](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

> In addition, modifier keys (such as
>   Shift) cause keydown events but not
>   keypress events.

Arrows <strike>fall</strike> *do not fall* in the same category as Shift, but are treated in a special way ... the keydown will do the trick ..

***Update***

After your comment [here is a sample that works](http://jsbin.com/uveko/2) in

- FF 3.5.x and 3.0.11
- IE 6, 7
- Google Chrome 4.0.x
- Safari 4.0.4

It only does not work on Opera (Edit: works on Opera 12.16) but it does not work with any key .. not just the arrows..

About the rate, you can not alter it from your code.. it is a system option (from BIOS and from keyboard settings in control panel *-windows-* )

Comment: I believe this will work in Firefox, but then won't work in Safari (and possibly other browsers) where keypress() works. I'm not aware of a plugin that selects the right one based on browser, but I'm guessing it's out there somewhere.

Comment: its the other way around. it doesnt work in FF but do work in Safari:/

Comment: I have added an update with a working sample.. (works in all browsers but opera..)

Comment: Arrow keys are not modifier keys and behave differently in terms of the events they fire in some browsers. For example, Firefox fires a `keypress` event for arrow keys but not for Shift.

Comment: @Tim, it fires a keypress.. but only one .. while the OP asks for a solution for continues events while the key is pressed.. I hear your though about the arrows not being modifiers..

Comment: Yes, I understand the OP's problem and I've faced it myself before. There isn't an easy answer to it, cross-browser. My comment was just to highlight the different behaviours of Shift and arrow keys.